# gets_s() is getting skipped

Tags: c, string, format, scanf

I have this piece of code that is supposed to ask the user to input some information:

```
char * nome = malloc(256);
char * cc = malloc(256);
char * morada = malloc(256);
char * tlf = malloc(20);
printf("Novo nome:");
gets_s(nome, sizeof(nome));
printf("Nova Morada:");
fflush(stdin);
gets_s(morada, sizeof(morada));
printf("Cartao de cidadao:");
fflush(stdin);
gets_s(cc, sizeof(cc));
printf("Novo Contacto:");
fflush(stdin);
gets_s(tlf, sizeof(tlf));
```

The first `gets_s()` get's skipped and I can't understand why, I've also tried to use `scanf("%s",nome)` and also tried to user some resolutions I've found through stack overflow, because as I far as I understood what happens with `scanf()` is that the last character is actually read "automatically" because it isn't consumed on the previous `scanf()` but I don't think this is the case since I've tried every suggestion I could find.
Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

EDIT:

```
char nome[256];
char cc[256];
char morada[256];
char tlf[20];

printf("Novo nome:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", nome);

printf("Nova Morada:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", morada);

printf("Cartao de cidadao:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", cc);

printf("Novo Contacto:");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s", tlf);
```

Comment: 1) `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behaviour 2) You don't check the any result of `malloc` and `gets_s`. 3) The bounds checking interfaces are optional. Why not use `fgets`? 4) a pointer is not an array. 5) Get your C book and read what `sizeof` does.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. first what do you mean by "invokes undefined behaviour"?
I've since used fgets() as you suggested but the result is the same, I've ditched fflush() because what I understood from your comment is that it's behaviour is not defined therefore it's not certain that it cleans the buffer.
Still getting the same result

Comment: Your biggest problem is in using `sizeof` in an inappropriate way.

Comment: Do you have any code before this that reads input? You have to be careful if you mix `gets_s()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: `sizeof(nome)` is probably just `4`, since it's the size of a pointer, not the size of the buffer it points to.

Comment: What do you think `sizeof(cc)` etc. yields? Use a debugger and check the results, you'd be surprised. After that, ask yourself why pointers are not called "array" and vice versa. Finally: you want to read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @DYZ I've sinced read the documentation and yeah what I was doing didn't make any sense, but even though I'm not using it I get the same results with fgets()

Comment: @Olaf I know what sizeof does... I've just followed the documentation on `gets_s()` even though I'm now using arrays instead of pointers and scanf("%s") I get exactly the same result, so what you've pointed out has nothing to do with this as far as I can tell

Comment: Well, »The function `fflush()` forces a write of all buffered data for the given **output or update stream**«. The result of calling `fflush()` on input streams is undefined.

Comment: No offence, but you apparently don't. Just follow my comment step-by-step. If you don't understand something, do some research. That's good training.

Comment: @Olaf check the edit

Comment: I think the problem is actually that I'm trying to read a string with spaces such as "foo bar foo" and the scanf reads only the first word because it encoutered a space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use `fgets()` than `scanf()` when you want to read strings containing spaces. Also note that `fflush(stdin)` results in undefined behavior, according to the Standard, though Microsoft supports defined behavior for this usage. Still, it is *not* portable, and probably should never be used.

When you use `fgets()` to read a line of input, the trailing newline is stored in the input buffer, so you will probably need to remove it. There are many ways to do this, but here I have used the `strchr()` function from `string.h` to write a little function, `eat_newline()`, that finds the newline and replaces it with the null character.

One of the advantages of using `fgets()`, though it is not used here, is that you can read in a line of input, and then use `sscanf()` to parse it, in the same way that you would use `scanf()`, but with more control, and the ability to rescan the same line of input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void eat_newline(char *str)
{
    char *find;    
    if ((find = strchr(str, '\n')) != NULL) {
        *find = '\0';
    }    
}

int main(void)
{
    char nome[256];
    char cc[256];
    char morada[256];
    char tlf[20];

    printf("Novo nome:");
    fgets(nome, sizeof nome, stdin);
    eat_newline(nome);

    printf("Nova Morada:");
    fgets(morada, sizeof morada, stdin);
    eat_newline(morada);

    printf("Cartao de cidadao:");
    fgets(cc, sizeof cc, stdin);
    eat_newline(cc);

    printf("Novo Contacto:");
    fgets(tlf, sizeof tlf, stdin);
    eat_newline(tlf);

    printf("nome: %s\n", nome);
    printf("morada: %s\n", morada);
    printf("cc: %s\n", cc);
    printf("tlf: %s\n", tlf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was by far the best answer and the one that actually a adressed my problem. Thank you for the detailed answer and example kind sir